# My Bootstrap Admin Theme wont work with fullcalendar js plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this problem when I tried to integrate the fullcalendar on my starter theme of admin bootstrap. I need to integrate this on my landing page. Here is the code

```js
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
   editable: true,
   eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
   events: [
    {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: '2015-02-01'
    },
    {
     title: 'Long Event',
     start: '2015-02-07',
     end: '2015-02-10'
    },

    {
     title: 'tite',
     start: '2015-02-07',
     end: '2015-02-10'
    },


    {
     title: 'flava design',
     start: '2015-05-10',
     end: '2015-05-27'
    },

    {
     id: 999,
     title: 'Repeating Event',
     start: '2015-02-09T16:00:00'
    },
    {
     id: 999,
     title: 'Repeating Event',
     start: '2015-02-16T16:00:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Conference',
     start: '2015-02-11',
     end: '2015-02-13'
    },
    {
     title: 'Meeting',
     start: '2015-02-12T10:30:00',
     end: '2015-02-12T12:30:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Lunch',
     start: '2015-02-12T12:00:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Meeting',
     start: '2015-02-12T14:30:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Happy Hour',
     start: '2015-02-12T17:30:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Dinner',
     start: '2015-02-12T20:00:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Birthday Party',
     start: '2015-02-13T07:00:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Click for Google',
     url: 'http://google.com/',
     start: '2015-02-28'
    }
   ]
  });
  
 });

</script>
<style>

#calendar {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }


</style>





  <!-- END OF IT -->
```

```html
<?php 
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION["username"]; 



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="ie6 ielt7 ielt8 ielt9"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="ie7 ielt8 ielt9"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="ie8 ielt9"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 9 ]><html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]--><!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> 
<html lang="en"><!--<![endif]--> 
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dashboard - Flava</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- SCRIPT FOR EVENT CALENDAR -->
<link href='fullcalendar-2.3.1/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar-2.3.1/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='fullcalendar-2.3.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.3.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>


  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
     <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </a> <a class="brand" href="#">Flava Design</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
       <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active">
         <a href="index.htm">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="settings.htm">Account Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="help.htm">Help</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="help.htm" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tours <b class="caret"></b></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
           <a href="help.htm">Introduction Tour</a>
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="help.htm">Project Organisation</a>
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="help.htm">Task Assignment</a>
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="help.htm">Access Permissions</a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider">
          </li>
          <li class="nav-header">
           Files
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="help.htm">How to upload multiple files</a>
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="help.htm">Using file version</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
       <form class="navbar-search pull-left" action="">
        <input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search" />
       </form>
       <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li>
         <a href="profile.htm"><?php 
         echo $username  ?></a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
     <div class="well" style="padding: 8px 0;">
      <ul class="nav nav-list">
       <li class="nav-header">
        Project Management System
       </li>
       <li class="active">
        <a href="home.php"><i class="icon-white icon-home"></i> Dashboard</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="projects.php"><i class="icon-folder-open"></i> Projects</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="tasks.htm"><i class="icon-check"></i> Tasks</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="messages.htm"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Messages</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="files.htm"><i class="icon-file"></i> Files</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="activity.htm"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i> Activity</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-header">
        Your Account
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="profile.htm"><i class="icon-user"></i> Profile</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="settings.htm"><i class="icon-cog"></i> Settings</a>
       </li>
       <li class="divider">
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="help.htm"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i> Help</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-header">
        Bonus Templates
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="gallery.htm"><i class="icon-picture"></i> Gallery</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="blank.htm"><i class="icon-stop"></i> Blank Slate</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span9">
     <h1>
      Dashboard
     </h1>
     <div class="hero-unit">
      <h1>
       Welcome!
      </h1>
      <p>
       Project Management System Designed by Flava
      </p>
      <p>
       <a href="help.htm" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Start Tour</a> <a class="btn btn-large">No Thanks</a>
      </p>
      <div id="calendar"></div>
      
     </div>




     <div class="well summary">
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="count">3</span> Projects</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="count">27</span> Tasks</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="count">7</span> Messages</a>
       </li>
       <li class="last">
        <a href="#"><span class="count">5</span> Files</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <h2>
      Recent Projects
     </h2>
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>
         Project
        </th>
        <th>
         Client
        </th>
        <th>
         Type
        </th>
        <th>
         Date
        </th>
        <th>
         View
        </th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>
         Nike.com Redesign
        </td>
        <td>
         Monsters Inc
        </td>
        <td>
         New Task
        </td>
        <td>
         4 days ago
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="#" class="view-link">View</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
         Nike.com Redesign
        </td>
        <td>
         Monsters Inc
        </td>
        <td>
         New Message
        </td>
        <td>
         5 days ago
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="#" class="view-link">View</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
         Nike.com Redesign
        </td>
        <td>
         Monsters Inc
        </td>
        <td>
         New Project
        </td>
        <td>
         5 days ago
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="#" class="view-link">View</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
         Twitter Server Consulting
        </td>
        <td>
         Bad Robot
        </td>
        <td>
         New Task
        </td>
        <td>
         6 days ago
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="#" class="view-link">View</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
         Childrens Book Illustration
        </td>
        <td>
         Evil Genius
        </td>
        <td>
         New Message
        </td>
        <td>
         9 days ago
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="#" class="view-link">View</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
         Twitter Server Consulting
        </td>
        <td>
         Bad Robot
        </td>
        <td>
         New Task
        </td>
        <td>
         16 days ago
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="#" class="view-link">View</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
         Twitter Server Consulting
        </td>
        <td>
         Bad Robot
        </td>
        <td>
         New Project
        </td>
        <td>
         16 days ago
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="#" class="view-link">View</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
         Twitter Server Proposal
        </td>
        <td>
         Bad Robot
        </td>
        <td>
         Completed Project
        </td>
        <td>
         20 days ago
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="#" class="view-link">View</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
     <ul class="pager">
      <li class="next">
       <a href="activity.htm">More &rarr;</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/site.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

It seems that the div calendar is not showing but when I create a new php page that only has the fullcalendar it works.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is you need to omit one of the declare resources of jquery. to work with the fullcalendar js plugin.

i've ommitted the declaration of jquery on bootstrap and use the jquery that comes with the fullcalendar package

Comment: and also the flow of declaration of script